# regular expression format url

Tags: regex, expression

need help to write regular expression to take change urls

from:
http://vermon.com/good/helping.html
NOTE: good may change at times to something different

to:
http://suresite.com/helping.html

PLEASE NOTE: I am changing the base url and taking out the word good

Comment: So, you always want to replace 'vermon.com/good' to 'suresite.com' ?

Comment: What's the question again? I mean I would just replace `http://vermon.com` with `http://suresite.com` and remove any `good/`

Comment: It would help if you specify what language you are using

Comment: The regular expression syntax is often specific to the tool you are using to interpret it, so it may be helpful to know what tools are you using. Beyond that, it would be much easier to see an attempt from yours to see how it can be improved.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with Java:

```
System.out.println(
    "http://vermon.com/good/helping.html"
        .replaceAll("(http://)[^/]+/good(/.+)", "$1suresite.com$2"));
```

Output:

```
http://suresite.com/helping.html
```