# Php regular expression echo characters after a string

Tags: php, regex

I have a large .txt file, within the .txt file, it contains the numbers 712 and other characters. example (712iu3 89234) or (712jnksuiosd). The characters after 712 will change, they may have spaces. I have a php script that reads the file line by line. I am trying to echo all characters after 712 If there are spaces I'd like to remove the spaces. I only need the first 20 characters excluding the spaces. So far I've tried

```
$file = new SplFileObject("1.txt");

// Loop until we reach the end of the file.
while (!$file->eof()) {
// Echo one line from the file.
echo $file->fgets();
}

// Unset the file to call __destruct(), closing the file handle.
$file = null;
```

Comment: I don't see where you attempt to attempt to extract the characters you want. It looks more like you want us to write your code for you. [This isn't the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46369870/regular-expression-format-url)

Comment: `splfileobject` is slower than simple `file()` in this case

Comment: You could try removing the spaces first as they seem to be in the way. Look at something simple like str_replace , maybe put the new lines with no spaces in an array. Post your code when you've got that working. 1/2 hour in the php manual and should get you there..

Comment: Is each `712xxxxx` type thing on it's own line or how are `712iu3 89234` and `712jnksuiosd` separated? And are they actually inside of parentheses `()`? And are these the only things in the file or other text and numbers mixed in?

Answer (score 0):

try using the code below

```
<?php 
$file = new SplFileObject("test.txt");

// Loop until we reach the end of the file.
while (!$file->eof()) {
    $newString = str_replace(' ', '', $file->fgets());
if (strpos($newString, '712') !== false) {
    $strWith712 = substr($newString, 0, 20);
    $post = strripos($strWith712, '712');
    $str =  substr ($strWith712, $post );
    echo $str;

}

}

$file = null;
?>
```

this replaces the white spaces and then searches for the string with the number '712' if a string is found then the letters after the number are printed
the `strripos` function is used to check the postiton of the string in a sentence from the last.

Comment: May be better to use `substr`, because `str_replace` will also remove 712 if it happens to occur again later in the string as part of the alphanumeric part, and you could also limit it to 20 chars like the OP wants to do. Just a suggestion.

Comment: Works but the code is capturing the string from beginning of line. Is there any way to capture all characters after 712 making sure that 712 is included in the string. Removing all spaces and then trim the text to 20 characters

Comment: @staceyseigle you want to "capture all characters after 712 making sure that 712 is included"? is that correct?

Comment: Very close. So here is an example of the text I am getting back once echo    helloword712allgood. I was hoping for 712allgood